# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (Javascript Objects)

Tags: javascript, object, jscript

I have trouble with my code below.

I have a Object with functions etc and I need a locale storage object too. Is this possible?
I always get the "Unexpected identifier" error trying to do this.

```
var object = {

    var STORAGE = new Object();
    STORAGE.one = null;
    STORAGE.two = null;
    STORAGE.three = null;
    STORAGE.four = null;

    one: function(){
        //function one
    },

    two: function() {
        //function 2
    }
};
```

Comment: You can't put arbitrary code in the middle of an object literal.

Comment: You are randomly throwing in code...

Comment: You've overlapped two different ways of constructing an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is achieved like this:

```
var object = (function(){
  var STORAGE = new Object();
    STORAGE.one = null;
    STORAGE.two = null;
    STORAGE.three = null;
    STORAGE.four = null;
  return {    
    one: function(){
        //function one
    },

    two: function() {
        //function 2
    }
  };
})();
```

Cheers

Comment: Glad it helped you. Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare variables or run arbitrary code inside an object literal.

You have to use a `property:` and a nested object literal:

```
var object = {

  STORAGE: {
    one: null,
    two: null
    // ...  
  }

  one: function () { }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
var object = {

    STORAGE: {
        one: null,
        two: null,
        three: null,
        four: null
    },

    one: function(){
        //function one
    },

    two: function() {
        //function 2
    }
};
```